# Expanding rational functions with minimal denominator

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I'm working with rational functions and I want to be able to put them in a specific form and then get a list of terms in which the numerators are monomials. Take for example

```
r[x_, y_, z_, v_] := x/(1 + y)^2 + y/v + z
```

What I would like is some function `rationalMonomialList` which gives me back

```
rationalMonomialList[r[x,y,z,v]]  (* output= {y/v, x/(1 + y)^2, z} *)
```

for `r` this is easy enough by taking

```
rationalMonomialList[rat_]:=
  Module[{rat0=Expand[rat]},Table[rat0[[i]],{i,1,Length[rat0]}]]
```

which is the answer I want. This lets me write rf as \begin{equation}r(x,y,z,v)=p(x,y,z,v)+q(x,y,z,v)+s(x,y,z,f)\end{equation}

where $p$ is a polynomial, $q$ is a laurent polynomial, and $s$ is a rational function. However, there are plenty of equivalent forms for rational functions, and this obviously won't work for most of them. As a counter example, The definition above gives the following:

```
rationalMonomialList[Apart[r[x,y,z,v]]] 
  (* out= {x/(1 + y)^2, y/(v (1 + y)^2), (2 y^2)/(v (1 + y)^2), y^3/(v (1 + y)^2), z} *)
```

Which is not of the form given above. What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly guarantee that this works for arbitrary rational functions, but if you replace `ExpandAll` with `FullSimplify` it works on the cases you have provided at least.

Also, if you have more than one term after `FullSimplify` then the `Head` of the whole expression will be `Plus`, and the arguments will be the terms. So I find it easier to turn it into a list using the following:

```
rationalMonomialList[expr_] :=
With[{simp=FullSimplify[expr]}, If[Head[simp] === Plus, List @@ simp, {simp} ]
```

Comment: I am always wary about using FullSimplify. I'm encountering these functions in a setting where I'm looking for exact solutions to some polynomial equations and there are cases where FullSimplify does not give me back something exactly equivalent to what I put in.

Answer (score 1):

Since you commented that you do not trust `FullSimplify` perhaps you can use more transparent tools such as [`Cancel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cancel.html) and [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html) to effect your manipulations.  I am not claiming this is robust but for your consideration:

```
reduce = Fold[Cancel @* Collect, #, Variables @ #] &;
```

Now:

```
Apart[r[x, y, z, v]]
reduce[%]
List @@ %
```

> ```
> (v x + y + 2 y^2 + y^3)/(v (1 + y)^2) + z
>
> y/v + x/(1 + y)^2 + z
>
> {y/v, x/(1 + y)^2, z}
> ```